# How do I pass an instance member function as callback to std::thread

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

I'm VERY new to C++. My experience has mostly been with javascript and java.

I'm using Xcode on Lion. The following code gives me a compilation error "Reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?"

```
class MyClass {
private:
    void handler() {
    }

public:
    void handleThings() {
        std::thread myThread(handler);
    }
};
```

I also tried `this->handler`, `&handler`, and other variations, but none of them worked. This code compiles though and accomplishes what I want it to:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    void handler() {
    }

public:
    void handleThings() {
        std::thread myThread([this]() {
            handler();
        });
    }
};
```

Why can't I pass a reference to a member function? Is my work-around the best solution?

Comment: that is not a "workaround"... that is the right way to do your task (one of). the second one, is to use `std::bind` instead of lambda.
to call a method of a class you have to provide an instance of that class (`this` pointer as first implicit parameter of any non static member-function). passing just an address of the method you want to call (w/o the instance) to `std::thread` ctor is not enough obviously.

Comment: depending on your tasks consider to use `std::async` instead of `std::thread`... in case if running thread just calc smth and exits (i.e. not an even loop handler)

Comment: I get it now. Your first comment zaufi as well as this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12765270/711902 taught me something.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
std::thread myThread(&MyClass::handler, this);
myThread.join();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::mem_fun`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fun/), if you dont want to use a lamda.

Are you able to do this?

```
std::thread myThread(std::mem_fun(&MyClass::handler),this);
```

`std::thread` accepts arguments to the function (which is the first argument) and  `this` is passed as an argument to the `mem_fun` object, which then calls the handler function on `this`.

You could also quite simply do the below, courtesy - [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

```
std::thread myThread(&MyClass::handler,this);
```

Comment: you don't need mem_fun here.

Answer (score 5):

Use `lambda` to access class members within a member function, you need to capture `this`. `[this]` is mandatory in below code:

```
void handleThings() 
{
    std::thread myThread([this]() {
        handler();
    });
}
```

You could capture `this` by reference but it's not as efficient as capturing it by value. because going through the reference requires double indirection (modulo compiler optimizations)

```
void handleThings() {
        std::thread myThread([&]() {
            handler();
        });
    }
```

`Lambdas` are usually a better choice than `bind`.

- Easier for readers to understand.
- More efficient.

Comment: `this` is just a pointer, so passing/capturing by value is quite ok... depending on completeness of C++11 support in compiler `this->handler()` may be required to resolve ambiguity.

Comment: How can I learn more about lambda vs. bind performance? Does this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8884445/711902 seem to indicate that performance is usually the same, at least with GCC 4.7? Or is the answerer talking about something else?

Comment: I haven't test it yet, but I read from C++11 books, like `Overview of the New C++ (C++0x)` mentions that.

Comment: What about `std::thread myThread(&MyClass::handler, this)` like bamboon suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function? Is that doing the same thing as std::bind? That seems like the cleanest solution.

Comment: @TrevorDixon, yes that works perfectly. It's very similar to `bind` and does the same thing in this case, but is not always exactly the same because the way `thread` handles its arguments doesn't support everything that `bind` supports, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21066704/981959 for a bit more detail