# c++11 Thread class how to use a class member function

Tags: c++, c++11

My programs looks like below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
    void foo(int n ) { std::cout << n << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::thread t1(&A::foo, std::ref(a), 100);

    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using the following command I get errors

```
g++ -o main main.cc -lpthread -std=c++11
```

Error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:39:0,
                  from check.cc:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<A>, int)>’:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A::*)(int); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>, int}]’
check.cc:13:42:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:61: error：no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<A>, int)>’
        typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                              ^
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1727:9: error：no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<A>, int)>’
          _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
          ^
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This isn't the right place for a reference wrapper. A simple pointer suffices, though, and achieves the desired result:

```
std::thread t1(&A::foo, &a, 100);
```

Comment: +1 For having the correct answer and not filing erroneous bugs on GCC bugzilla like some kind of idiot.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT: RETRACTION**

Kerrek is correct here: I erroneously assumed that the `std::thread` constructor and `std::bind` were by design identical interfaces. However, the automatic conversion of arguments from `reference_wrapper<A>` to `A&` is specified for only `std::bind` in [func.bind.bind]/10:

> The values of the *bound arguments* `v1, v2, ..., vN` and their corresponding types `V1, V2, ..., VN` depend on the types `TiD` derived from the call to `bind` and the *cv*-qualifiers *cv* of the call wrapper `g` as follows:
>
> - if `TiD` is `reference_wrapper<T>`, the argument is `tid.get()` and its type `Vi` is `T&`;
> - ...

So this particular use of `reference_wrapper<A>` is *not* supported by `std::thread`, but *is* supported by `std::bind`. The fact that `std::thread` behaves identically to `std::bind` in this instance in other/older compilers is the bug, not the behavior of 4.8 line GCC releases.

I'll leave the incorrect answer here with this explanation in hopes that others won't make this same mistake in the future.

**Short (but INCORRECT) answer**

This is apparently a bug in the standard library included with GCC 4.8. The code is correctly compiled by:

- [GCC 4.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32d2a69ced1eec67)
- [GCC 4.6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1184cec183a6654)
- [clang r198621 (a post-3.4 release trunk revision)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa54ac837830a10d)
- [MSVC2013](http://rextester.com/CPODMR87328)

**Long (and also INCORRECT) answer:**

The effects of the `std::thread` constructor

```
template <class F, class ...Args>
explicit thread(F&& f, Args&&... args);
```

are detailed in C++11 30.3.1.2 [thread.thread.constr]/4:

> The new thread of execution executes
>
> ```
> INVOKE(DECAY_COPY(std::forward<F>(f)),
>        DECAY_COPY(std::forward<Args>(args))...)
> ```
>
> with the calls to `DECAY_COPY` being evaluated in the constructing thread.

`DECAY_COPY` is described in 30.2.6 [thread.decaycopy]/1:

> In several places in this Clause the operation `DECAY_COPY(x)` is used. All such uses mean call the function `decay_copy(x)` and use the result, where `decay_copy` is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> template <class T> typename decay<T>::type decay_copy(T&& v)
> { return std::forward<T>(v); }
> ```

In the invocation in the OP `std::thread t1(&A::foo, std::ref(a), 100);` all three arguments are rvalues that `DECAY_COPY` will replicate into objects in the new thread's environment before the invocation, whose effect is described in 20.8.2 [func.require]/1:

> Define `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> - `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
> - `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
> - ...

For the code in the OP, `f` is a pointer to member function of class `A` with value `&A::foo`, `t1` is an lvalue `reference_wrapper<A>` whose stored reference refers to `a`, and `t2` is an `int` with value `100`. The second bullet of 20.8.2/1 applies. Since `t1` is a `reference_wrapper`, `*t1` evaluates to the stored reference (per 20.8.3.3/1) and the invocation in the new thread is effectively

```
(a.*&A::foo)(100);
```

So yes, the standard describes the behavior of the OP exactly as expected.

EDIT: Oddly, [GCC 4.8 correctly compiles the very similar example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2fb813e412e9802):

```
class A {
public:
    void foo(int n) { std::cout << n << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto foo = std::bind(&A::foo, std::ref(a), 100);
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, how exactly did you conclude that "`*t1` evaluates to the stored reference"? My 20.8.3.3 doesn't say that...

Comment: @KerrekSB Because I was under the erroneous assumption that `*t1` "magically" invokes `operator T&`.

Comment: Haha, +1 for the fix, and for digging through all the details of `INVOKE`. It's fairly involved, and any kind of systematic exposition is always appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Regarding your question title I would use a lambda for thread construction. With or without references, via calling member functions or binding parameters.

```
 std::thread t1([&] { a.foo(100); });
```

Comment: This seems like a much "cleaner" approach, ie don't expose the parameters or object or even the function to the thread, just give the thread all it wants, which is a `void (*)(void)` (well, that's the easiest way to describe it.)

Answer (score 7):

GCC 4.8 is correct, `std::thread` and other components defined in terms of *INVOKE* must not be implemented in terms of `std::bind`.  They must not invoke nested bind expressions and must use perfect forwarding for bound arguments (rather than forwarding them as lvalues as `std::bind` does), and additionally as you discovered they do not unwrap `reference_wrapper` objects.  In GCC 4.8 I introduced an internal implementation detail, `__bind_simple`, for use by `std::thread` etc. that doesn't have the full `std::bind` behaviour.

While the other differences from `std::bind` are desirable, I think the *INVOKE* operation should still support `reference_wrapper` objects, so I filed a defect report, see [LWG 2219](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2219).

Comment: Would something like `std::thread t(&A::foo, &a, std::ref(b));` also be illegal (assuming a member `A::foo(Bar&)` for example. I get [something similar](http://ideone.com/x2O6eU) to compile on gcc 4.8.2, and I am wondering whether that a bug or the behaviour mandated by the standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza, that is required to work. The defect is that reference_wrappers are not supported for the class object on which you are invoking the member, wrappers work fine for the arguments to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is ref(obj) returns a reference (alias) to an object not a pointer(address)! to work with threads we need pointers not references! See Below a handy program to use function pointers with threads:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "vector"
    #include "string"
    #include "thread"
    #include "atomic"
    #include "functional"

    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "string.h"
    #include "assert.h"

    using namespace std;
    //__________________________Global variables_________________________________________________

    atomic<int> var(0);

    //__________________________class____________________________________________________________

    class C
    {
    public:

        C()
        {}

        static void addition (int a, int b)
        {
            for(int i= 0; i< a+b; i++)
                var++;
        }

        void subtraction (int a, int b)
        {
            for(int i= 0; i< a+b; i++)
                var--;
        }
    };

    class D : std::atomic<int>
    {
    public:
        D() : std::atomic<int>(0)
        {}

        void increase_member (int n)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
                fetch_add(1);
        }

        int get_atomic_val()
        {
            return this->load();
        }
    };

    //________________________________functions________________________________________________

    void non_member_add (int a, int b)
    {
        for(int i= 0; i< a+b; i++)
            var++;
    }

    //__________________________________main____________________________________________________

    int main ()
    {
        int a=1, b=5;

    // (I)...........................................static public member function (with no inheritance).........................................

        void (* add_member_func_ptr)(int,int) = C::addition;            // pointer to a static public member function

        //defining thread pool for ststic public member_add_ptr

        vector<thread> thread_pool;

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            thread_pool.push_back(thread(add_member_func_ptr,a,b));
        }

        for(thread& thr: thread_pool)
            thr.join();

        cout<<"static public member function (with no inheritance)\t"<<var<<endl;

        //defining thread pool for ststic public member function

        var=0;

        thread_pool.clear();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            thread_pool.push_back(thread(C::addition,a,b));             //void (* add_member_func_ptr)(int,int) is equal to C::addition
        }

        for(thread& thr: thread_pool)
            thr.join();

        cout<<"static public member function (with no inheritance)\t"<<var<<endl;

    // (II)..............................................non-static public member function (with no inheritance)...................................

        C bar;

        void (C::* sub_member_func_ptr)(int,int) = & C::subtraction;            // pointer to a non-static public member function

        var=0;

        //defining thread pool for non-ststic public member function

        thread_pool.clear();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            thread_pool.push_back(thread(sub_member_func_ptr,bar,a,b));
        }

        for(thread& thr: thread_pool)
            thr.join();

        cout<<"non-static public member function (with no inheritance)\t"<<var<<endl;

        var=0;

        //defining thread pool for non-ststic public member function

        thread_pool.clear();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            thread_pool.push_back(thread(&C::subtraction,bar,a,b));         //void (C::* sub_member_func_ptr)(int,int) equals & C::subtraction;
        }

        for(thread& thr: thread_pool)
            thr.join();

        cout<<"non-static public member function (with no inheritance)\t"<<var<<endl;


    // (III)................................................non-member function .................................................

        void (* non_member_add_ptr)(int,int) = non_member_add;              //pointer to a non-member function

        var=0;

        //defining thread pool for non_member_add

        thread_pool.clear();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            thread_pool.push_back(thread(non_member_add,a,b));
        }

        for(thread& thr: thread_pool)
            thr.join();

        cout<<"non-member function\t"<<var<<endl<<endl;

    // (IV)...........................................non-static public member function (with inheritance).........................

        D foo;

        void (D::* member_func_ptr) (int) = & D::increase_member;                  //pointer to a non-static public member function of a derived class

        //defining thread pool for non-ststic public member function of a derived class

        thread_pool.clear();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            thread_pool.push_back(thread(member_func_ptr,&foo,10));                 //use &foo because this is derived class!
        }

        for(thread& thr: thread_pool)
            thr.join();

        cout<<"non-static public member function (with inheritance)\t"<<foo.get_atomic_val()<<endl;

        //defining thread pool for non-ststic public member function

        D poo;

        thread_pool.clear();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            reference_wrapper<D> poo_ref= ref(poo);

            D& poo_ref_= poo_ref.get();             //ref(obj) returns a reference (alias) to an object not a pointer(address)!

            D* d_ptr= &poo;                         //to work with thread we need pointers not references!


            thread_pool.push_back(thread(&D::increase_member, d_ptr,10));             //void (D::* member_func_ptr) (int) equals & D::increase_member;
        }

        for(thread& thr: thread_pool)
            thr.join();

        cout<<"non-static public member function (with inheritance)\t"<<poo.get_atomic_val()<<endl<<endl;


        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that i got the same error just by giving incompatible arguments to std::bind/std::thread. Like giving a pointer to a base class when a more specific pointer was in the signature of the actual function.