# How to call member function of first class in second class member function in thread c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have two classes.

```
class first
{
    public:
        int sum (int a, int b)
        {
            return a+b;
        }
};

class second
{
    private:
        std::thread t1, t2;
        int sum (int a, int b, int c)
        {
            return a+b+c;
        }
    public:
        void execute()
        {
            t1 = std::thread (&second::sum, this, 10,20,30);                //calling same class function
            t2 = std::thread (&first::sum, /*what will be here*/, 10,20);   // trying to call another class function
        }

};

int main()
{
    second s;
    s.execute();
    return 0;
}
```

What i need to pass in place of /* what will be here */

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an instance of `first` (or a pointer to a `first` instance that will live at least as long as the thread):

Passing an instance:

```
first f;
t2 = std::thread (&first::sum, f, 10,20);
```

Passing a pointer:

```
// assume m_f is a data member of type first
t2 = std::thread (&first::sum, &m_f, 10,20);
```

Which one to chose depends on the required semantics. In this case, it makes little sense for `first::sum` to be a member non-static member function (or a member function at all).

If you chose to make `first::sum` a `static` member, then you would need no instance of `first`:

```
t2 = std::thread (&first::sum, 10, 20);
```

Comment: You mean to say i need to create an instance of class first in class second?

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Yes, `add` is a non-static member function, so it needs an instance of `first` to act upon.

Comment: `std::thread` [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21066704/241631) have special handling for `reference_wrapper`. Also see Casey's long explanation above Jonathan's answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. But I don't want to create an instance of class "first". If i make the add function static in class first. then how to call it? what i need to pass in place of /* what will be here*/

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Then you just need two parameters, i.e. the two `ints`. I added an example.