# How to wrap a call to `std::thread` constructor? (that works with gcc, VS and icpc)

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread, icc

## Original Post (with errors)

I want to wrap a call to std::thread constructor (to keep track of all threads running so I can join them or do other things). In this example, the `t1` thread gets constructed properly, but the `t2` thread doesn't using gcc 4.8.1. However, on Windows (VS2012) it compiles without error and runs without error. Based on the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059115/c11-thread-class-how-to-use-a-class-member-function), this may appear to be a bug in gcc, but arguably it is actually a bug in VS. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
    void foo(int n ) { std::cout << n << std::endl; }
};

template<class F, class Arg>
std::thread& wrapper(F&& f, Arg&& a)
{
   std::thread* t = new std::thread(f,a,100);
   return *t;
}

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::thread t1(&A::foo, &a, 100);
    t1.join();

    std::thread t2 = wrapper(&A::foo, &a);
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler error

```
-bash-4.1$ make
g++ -std=c++11    main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:41: error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(std::thread&)’
     std::thread t2 = wrapper(&A::foo, &a);
                                         ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/thread:125:5: error: declared here
     thread(thread&) = delete;
     ^
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

## Update

I asked the wrong question here and am about to delete it, but because the answers are helpful, I will leave it. The problem was that the *Intel icpc 14.0* compiler (not gcc 4.8.1) was [throwing the same error regarding `bind` as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059115/c11-thread-class-how-to-use-a-class-member-function). And it has nothing to do with the "wrapper" but just calling std::thread with a member function instead of static function.

The complaints about the memory leak are 100% valid, but that was me making an unfortunate simplification to the example (from my real code). The actual code saves the threads in a container and deletes the threads on destruction.

Here is a better example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
    void foo() { }

    template<class Function, class Arg>
    std::thread* wrapper(Function&& f, Arg&& a)
    {
        auto t = new std::thread(f,a);
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::thread t1(&A::foo, &a);
    t1.join();

    std::thread* t2 = a.wrapper(&A::foo, &a);
    t2->join();
    delete t2;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output for `g++` (4.8.1) which works

```
-bash-4.1$ make CXX=g++
g++ -lpthread -std=c++11    main.cpp   -o main
```

and the output for the Intel compiler `icpc` (14.0) which doesn't work

```
-bash-4.1$ make CXX=icpc
icpc -lpthread -std=c++11    main.cpp   -o main
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/functional(1697): error: class "std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)()> (A *)>" has no member "type"
        typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of class "std::_Bind_simple<_Callable (_Args...)> [with _Callable=std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)()>, _Args=<A *>]" at line 1753
            instantiation of "std::_Bind_simple_helper<_Callable, _Args...>::__type std::__bind_simple(_Callable &&, _Args &&...) [with _Callable=void (A::*)(), _Args=<A *>]" at line 137 of "/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/thread"
            instantiation of "std::thread::thread(_Callable &&, _Args &&...) [with _Callable=void (A::*)(), _Args=<A *>]" at line 20 of "main.cpp"

/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/functional(1726): error: class "std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)()> (A *)>" has no member "type"
          typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type
                                                   ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of class "std::_Bind_simple<_Callable (_Args...)> [with _Callable=std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)()>, _Args=<A *>]" at line 1753
            instantiation of "std::_Bind_simple_helper<_Callable, _Args...>::__type std::__bind_simple(_Callable &&, _Args &&...) [with _Callable=void (A::*)(), _Args=<A *>]" at line 137 of "/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/thread"
            instantiation of "std::thread::thread(_Callable &&, _Args &&...) [with _Callable=void (A::*)(), _Args=<A *>]" at line 20 of "main.cpp"

compilation aborted for main.cpp (code 2)
make: *** [all] Error 2
-bash-4.1$
```

Comment: That's a terrible wrapper. Why do you allocate objects dynamically?!

Comment: Your Current Wrapper is also leaking memory. You are calling `new` to create the thread object but you are not calling `delete` to dealloc the memory.

Comment: No, this one is definitely a bug in Visual Studio, and is 100% unrelated to the link you provided, which has to do with `std::ref`, wheras your question is about thread copy constructors.

Comment: @KerrekSB -agreed it is a terrible wrapper. It was a bad example, but the problem is not the memory leak, but that I can't get std::thread to construct with `icpc` as shown.

Answer (score 5):

Your wrapper should be like this:

```
template<class F, class Arg>
std::thread wrapper(F&& f, Arg&& a)
{
    return std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Arg>(a));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make a difference with the Intel compiler (icpc version 14.0).

Answer (score 1):

`std::thread` is not copyable. Given that `wrapper` returns a `std::thread&`, `wrapper(&A::foo, &a);` is an lvalue, and thus the initialisation of `t2` requires a copy. That's what the compiler error is about.

Sadly, some versions of Visual Studio will happily perform a move here, even though there are no rvalues involved.

Something like `std::thread* t = new std::thread(f,a,100); return *t;` is pretty much the same as `return *new std::thread(f,a,100);`, and that clearly shows the [memory leak operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839943/46642): `*new`. Don't do this.

While not copyable, `std::thread` is movable. You just have to make it so that `wrapper(&A::foo, &a);` is an rvalue. That can be done simply by writing the function in the most natural style, like so:

```
template<class F, class Arg>
std::thread wrapper(F&& f, Arg&& a)
{
    return std::thread(f, a, 100);
}
```

This however fails to correctly forward the arguments preserving their value category (as is, it turns rvalues into lvalues), even though it's not a problem for this particular example. In order to have general applicability, the function body should forward the arguments properly, like so: `return std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Arg>(a), 100);`.