# Having problems passing multiple arguments from a function into a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I hope this isn't a stupid question. Please do not vote this down, I am a beginner with multithreading.

I've come into a problem when writing arguments into a thread from a function from a class. Here it is.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

#include<thread>

#include<sstream>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <ctime>
//
#include<atomic>
#include<functional>
//
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

#include"Directory.hpp"
#include"Tests.hpp"
//#define NUM_THREADS 2

using namespace std;

/*
template<class T> void f(T)
void addThreadNoArgs(T) {
    thread
}
*/

int main() {
    Emotions e;
    DictObj d;
    //Time t;
    //User u;
    Self s;
    Tests test;
    vector < thread > threads;

    int i = 200;


    Emotions temp;

    //pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    //-----------------------------------------------
    e.setEmo(50, 50, 25, 50, 40, 50, 30, 20, 10, 20);
    temp.setEmo(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

    s.setEmotions(e);
    s.setTempEmo(temp);



    /*
    int rc;
    int tc;
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, s.tempEmotions, s, e, temp, 200);
    tc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, test.testEmoALL, NULL);
    */
    //----------------------------------------------
    //threads.push_back(thread(&Self::tempEmotions,s,e,temp,200));
    thread first(&Self::tempEmotions, s, e, temp, i, ref(s));
    thread second(&Tests::testEmoALL, ref(test));
    //first.join();
    //second.join();

    cout << endl << "First and second completed";


    //first.detach();
    //second.detach();
    //----------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

Errors

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c "NO-DELETE.cpp" -lpthread (in directory: /home/courtneymaroney/Desktop/Courtney/Documents/AI/NEW)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:39:0,
                 from NO-DELETE.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int)>(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int, std::reference_wrapper<Self>)>’:
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:137:59:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int); _Args = {Self&, Emotions&, Emotions&, int&, std::reference_wrapper<Self>}]’
NO-DELETE.cpp:71:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int)>(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int, std::reference_wrapper<Self>)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int)>(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int, std::reference_wrapper<Self>)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
Compilation failed.
```

The line that's causing the problem is with the following line:
 `thread first(&Self::tempEmotions, s, e, temp, i, ref(s));`

I've tried looking in several places to figure out how to make this work with several class-arguments, but I can't seem to find the answer. thread second works though, so I am convinced it has to do with the arguments.

EDIT (11/8/16): I tried to move the arguments around in both the source file and the `int main()` file, but it did not work. I am still having this issue. I also tried to create a new Self class and reference it to that, but it also did not work.
    ALSO-- When I try to separate each argument in the line of code by          pressing "enter", the code error is brought down to the last part; `);` The same errors exist.

Answer (score 1):

What is your tempEmotions definition?

The first argument to a member function is always a pointer to `this` (your object), unless it's a static func.

[How do I pass an instance member function as callback to std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453329/how-do-i-pass-an-instance-member-function-as-callback-to-stdthread)

Comment: `void tempEmotions(Self robot, Emotions original, Emotioms temp, int seconds)`

Comment: The problem is the last argument: `thread first(&Self::tempEmotions, s, e, temp, i, ref(s));` You're trying to send a reference to s, but the tempEmotions func doesn't want it.

Comment: If I try to have no ref(s), it says that it's the wrong number of arguments and still gives me errors. Could you help me with that? Should I post the errors and such associated with that?

Comment: Try cleaning up. Creating a .cpp new file containing only classes/functions that you're worried about.

Comment: Continuing from my comment above... post errors when compiling on that source file. Experiment with only that source file. Try changing argument order and see how the compile errors change.

Comment: I'll try that. If errors still occur, I'll post them.      Although, it would be hard to do this. I have one file where all the classes are defined. I probably don't need that many #include 's but I can post the method if you'd like (the entire method). Most of my classes are intertwined, so this would be extremely difficult.

Comment: `thread first(&Self::tempEmotions, 200, e, temp, s, ref(s));`   <br/>Produces the following set of errors (first couple ones):<br/>`/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Self::*)(int, Emotions, Emotions, Self)>(int, Emotions, Emotions, Self, std::reference_wrapper<Self>)>’:`

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't figure out how to format the comment. Anyways, continuing the list:    `test-10-21-2016.cpp:63:59:   required from here` `/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Self::*)(int, Emotions, Emotions, Self)>(int, Emotions, Emotions, Self, std::reference_wrapper<Self>)>’     typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not exactly sure what went wrong, but I created a separate class within the file, and got around it somehow. I'm sure there's a better solution, but this is a temporary fix until someone can help me further. This is what I did:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<vector>
#include<string
#include<fstream>

#include<thread>

#include<sstream>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <ctime>
//
//#include<atomic>
//
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

#include"Directory.hpp"
#include"Tests.hpp"
//#define NUM_THREADS 2

using namespace std;

/*
template<typename _Tp>
class T {
    public:
        _Tp getT() { return t;}
    private: 
        _Tp t;
    };
    */
class RunF {
    private:
            Emotions e;
        DictObj d;
        Self s;
        Tests test;
        Emotions temp;
    public:
        void setE(Emotions emo) {e = emo;}
        void setTE(Emotions emo) {temp = emo;}
        void setS(Self emo) {s= emo;}
        void setT(Tests emo) {test = emo;}
        void setD(DictObj emo) { d = emo;}
        //----------------------
        void function0() { test.testEmoALL(); }
        void function1() {
            s.tempEmotions(200, e, temp, s);
        }
};
int main() {

Emotions e;
DictObj d;
//Time t;
User u;
Self s;
Tests test;
vector < thread > threads;
Emotions temp;



//Emotions temp;

//pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
//-----------------------------------------------
e.setEmo(50, 50, 25, 50, 40, 50, 30, 20, 10, 20);
temp.setEmo(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

s.setEmotions(e);
s.setTempEmo(temp);

//const Self &testSelf();
/*
int rc;
int tc;
rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, s.tempEmotions, s, e, temp, 200);
tc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, test.testEmoALL, NULL);
*/
//----------------------------------------------
//threads.push_back(thread(&Self::tempEmotions,s,e,temp,200));
//--------
RunF f;
f.setE(e);
f.setTE(temp);
f.setS(s);
f.setT(test);
f.setD(d);
//--------
thread first(&RunF::function1, ref(f));
thread second(&Tests::testEmoALL, ref(test));
first.join();
second.join();

cout << endl << "First and second completed";


//first.detach();
second.detach();
//----------------------------------------------

return 0;
}
```

The class, RunF, is where I define the functions as a kind of local class to the file, rather than importing the classes from the file from the directory right into the main thread. I'm not sure why this works, but I suspect it's because there may be some disconnect with local classes in the file and different files. I can also find that, my directory file compiles, but it does not build, and says it needs a `main`. If someone can explain why this happens, it would be greatly appreciated. For now, the separate class in the main file is a temporary fix.